# How to print all uppercase words in a region with sed and friends?

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

How can I use `sed` to print all uppercase words which are in the area between `\begin{mcstas}` and `\end{mcstas}` in the file `foo.tex`?

The following example contains a minimal example of foo.tex:

```
\begin{mcstas}
DEFINE COMPONENT  child_name COPY parent_name
SETTING PARAMETERS (newpar1, newpar2) 
INITIALIZE COPY  parent_name EXTEND 
SAVE
\end{mcstas}
foo FALSE POSITIVE
\begin{mcstas}
DEFINE COMPONENT  name ...
\end{mcstas}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit tricky as you ask it: the "between `\begin{mcstas}` and `\end{mcstas}`" part is what `sed` can do easily, but the "print all uppercase words" part is best done with `grep` rather than `sed`. So if you just want to get it done, you can do:

```
$ sed '/\\begin{mcstas}/,/\\end{mcstas}/!d' foo.tex | grep -ow '[A-Z]\+'
DEFINE
COMPONENT
COPY
SETTING
PARAMETERS
INITIALIZE
COPY
EXTEND
SAVE
DEFINE
COMPONENT
```

Here's how a single `sed` command that does the same (as you initially asked) would look:

```
$ sed -n '/\\begin{mcstas}/,/\\end{mcstas}/!d; s/\b/\n/g; :a; /^[A-Z]\+\n/P; s/[^\n]*\n//; ta' foo.tex
DEFINE
COMPONENT
COPY
SETTING
PARAMETERS
INITIALIZE
COPY
EXTEND
SAVE
DEFINE
COMPONENT
```

Comment: Aha, if I'd known how to do that between-pieces bit of magic with sed I could have eliminated the awk part of my answer!

Comment: I agree that "printing the capital words" part really calls out for grep, but the multiline part of this problem inspired me to look elsewhere for a solution. It's another tool I could have used, though.

Comment: @erewok Yeah, `grep` alone can't do it either.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I'm curious, what does `!d` do in `/\\end{mcstas}/!d` ?

Comment: @jkshah You should read that part as `/\\begin{mcstas}/,/\\end{mcstas}/!d`: _not delete_ what is between `\begin{mcstas}` and `\end{mcstas}`; which is the `sed` way of expressing "delete everything outside that range".

Comment: @LevLevitsky the reason for a question was that it did blunder to my trial. `!d` is getting replaced by last issued command in the terminal! Not sure if some custom setting in shell is causing this.

Comment: @jkshah Wow, even inside the single quotes? What terminal is that?

Comment: @LevLevitsky It's tcsh. `!d` is being treated as one of the special commands used to retrieve history and replaces it with last issued command starting with `d`

Comment: @jkshah How do you deal with string literals containing `!` then? Probably by escaping it as `\!`?

Answer (score 4):

You could use awk to spit out the lines you want and then pipe to sed and replace everything but the capital letters (which I suggested because I always fail to use sed to do anything multiline, but I prefer it over awk).

There's probably a better solution, but this is the first one that occurred to me:

```
awk '/begin/,/end/' yourfile.txt | sed 's/[^A-Z ]//g' | sed '/^$/d'
```

That last bit at the end simply deletes any remaining empty lines.

This produces the following output:

```
DEFINE COMPONENT   COPY
SETTING PARAMETERS
INITIALIZE COPY   EXTEND 
SAVE
DEFINE COMPONENT
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) alone :

One-liner version :

```
perl -lne '/\\begin\{mcstas\}/../\\end\{mcstas\}/ and /\p{Lu}+/ and print $& for split;' file
```

Expanded version :

```
perl -lne '
    if (/\\begin\{mcstas\}/ .. /\\end\{mcstas\}/) {
        /\p{Lu}+/ and print $& for split;
    }
' file
```

We can use the POSIX `[[:upper:]]` too instead of `\p{Lu}` or `\p{Uppercase_Letter}`

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-\p{}-and-\P{}

Comment: Seems more natural to use a range operator: `if( /\\begin\{mcstas\}/ .. /\\end\{mcstas]} ) { ... } `

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '/\\(begin|end){mcstas}/{f=!f} f && /^[[:upper:]]+$/' file
DEFINE
COMPONENT
COPY
SETTING
PARAMETERS
INITIALIZE
COPY
EXTEND
SAVE
DEFINE
COMPONENT
```

or if you want them only printed once:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '/\\(begin|end){mcstas}/{f=!f} f && /^[[:upper:]]+$/ && !seen[$0]++' file
DEFINE
COMPONENT
COPY
SETTING
PARAMETERS
INITIALIZE
EXTEND
SAVE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`:

```
awk '/\\end/{f=0} toupper($0)==$0 && NF;  /\\begin/{f=1}' RS=" |\n" file
```